# How to reduce the size of vector when removing elements from it?

Tags: c++, vector, c++11, resize, splice

I'm writing a program which memory is limited base on input size. Say the input size is 1000, then I store them in a vector of size 1000. Later when I'm processing the data in this vector, whenever an element is done processed, I push it into my second vector and use vector.erase to remove it from the original vector. So I thought I'm always using 1000 size of memory because there are always 1000 elements stored in these two vectors in total.

But I'm wrong, it turns out I used 2000 memory because `erase` doesn't reduce the size of vector when elements removed... I guess it's the same for `splice` is it?

So is there a way I can make my program use only 1000 memory? I can solve it by adding an attribut and mark whether the element's  processed, but I feel it's not the best way. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This technique to try and shrink capacity can be used both in C++03 and C++11:

```
std::vector<int> v;
// ...
std::vector<int>(v.begin(), v.end()).swap(v);
```

This [live example](http://ideone.com/S79545) contains a demonstration. Whether the technique is effective depends on how much memory the implementation allocates when initializing the temporary vector with the elements of `v`.

In C++11, the member function [`shrink_to_fit()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit) can be invoked to perform a non-binding request to shrink the capacity of the vector to the size required to hold the elements currently in the container.

Notice, that "*non-binding*" means that the implementation is not required by the Standard to actually satisfy this request.

Comment: Note that the trick is also non-binding in the sense that that capacity could be (but probably isn't) arbitrarily large, even larger than the original. Do any compilers actually ignore a `shrink_to_fit()` request? I think a bit too much emphasis has been placed on it being non-binding so you might scare away people from using it.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried this method, the memory usage appear to be even higher than before...I'm using this way to measure: `/usr/bin/time -f "%Uu %MKB"` in terminal, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

`C++11` added a function `shrink_to_fit()` to `std::vector`. If you're looking for a way to reduce the size of a vector, after removing elements from it, that would be the way to go. [Here is more information on it.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/shrink_to_fit/)

Comment: Thanks, but I tried this method, the memory usage appear to be even higher than before...I'm using this way to measure: /usr/bin/time -f "%Uu %MKB" in terminal, any idea?

Comment: I think the underlying issue is that you create and populate a new vector while the old one is being unpopulated. The total memory impact is double the size of the original vector because you are simultaneously depopulating the old one and populating the new one. Essentially, you are copying the elements as they're being accessed into a different location in memory where the new vector lies. The only way to avoid this would be to mark each element as it has been processed, as you noted in your original post.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean.. Say I have 1 2 3 4 5 in old_vector, I do this : `new_vector.push_back(old_vector[3])`, then `old_vector.erase(old_vector.begin+3)`  Isn't the total memory of these 2 vectors added up always at most 5+1 =6 in this case?

Comment: Each `std::vector` under the hood is represented by an array that is reallocated when it is of insufficient size. You start with `old_vector` at size 1000, and create `new_vector`, which is allocated at some other location. When you delete from `old_vector`, the underlying array does not change in size, but it is reshuffled as necessary. It is then added to `new_vector`'s underlying array, pending reallocation. Note that these things happen in two different places, meaning there is no way to guarantee that, even if you resize `old_vector`, `new_vector` will occupy that space freed.